# What is the lifespan of pvc cement?

Tags: plumbing, maintenance, pvc

My house is 32 years old, due to other reasons I have my bathroom floor removed. 
Looking down at the PVC pipe that is used for the tub, sink and toilet got me wondering.

What is the lifespan of PVC glue when used to connect two joints?
Would hot and/or cold water flowing through the pipe cause the lifespan to shorten?

Answer (score 9):

When installed properly, the life should be indefinite. The hot/cold should have little effect, unless those temperatures are extreme.

Comment: +1. PVC cement is a "chemical weld" between the pipes, melting them into each other. Done right, it shouldn't let go.

Comment: Correct, it is a solvent weld, not a glue. As with all welding, it should be as strong as the parent material. Which over time can get brittle and will probably split well away from the welds as extrusion stress builds in a linear stress riser in the material leading to a lengthwise split.